# if condition isn't work in task "longest common prefix"

Tags: arrays, scala, if-statement, while-loop

Hy, I have misunderstanding with this code

By the task I should write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".
So my soluthion :

```
def longestCommonPrefix(strs: Array[String]): String = {
  val size = strs.length

  if (size == 0) {
    " "
  } else {
  val j = strs.sortWith(_.length < _.length)
    val minStr = Math.min(j(0).length, j(size - 1).length)
    var i: Int = 0
    while (i < minStr && j(0).take(i) == j(size - 1).take(i))
    i=i+1
    val  pre = j(0).substring(0, i-1)
    pre
  }
}

    Example: val name  = Array("flower","flow","flight")
             print(longestCommonPrefix(name))
    output: fl
```

And it's correct , but when I put Array("") I have en error

```
String index out of range: -1
```

why this condition isn't work ?

```
 if (size == 0) { " "}
```

Comment: Because `Array("")` doesn't have a `size` equals to `0`, but rather `1` because it has an element, the empty string.

Comment: BTW, this is a nice way to solve the problem: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/qIyCUbuBR1K7Guvckrk9Rg/2

Comment: A one line solution: `def lcp(strs: Array[String]): String = strs.reduceOption((x, y) => x.inits.find(y.startsWith).get).getOrElse("")`